# Magento prototype.js error: "throw $continue" is deprecated, use "return" instead

Tags: magento, prototypejs

in Firefox, we can see this error:

```
Error: "throw $continue" is deprecated, use "return" instead
```

We can see this error is raised by some line code (line 5878) in "DEPRECATED" block in prototype.js

We can remove this line to go around this error, but:
- why this "DEPRECATED" block kept in here?
- why my program would run this deprecated code? It looks like before, we didn't have this error.
- can we remove whole this block?

```
/*------------------------------- DEPRECATED -------------------------------*/

Hash.toQueryString = Object.toQueryString;

var Toggle = { display: Element.toggle };

Element.Methods.childOf = Element.Methods.descendantOf;

var Insertion = {
  Before: function(element, content) {
    return Element.insert(element, {before:content});
  },

  Top: function(element, content) {
    return Element.insert(element, {top:content});
  },

  Bottom: function(element, content) {
    return Element.insert(element, {bottom:content});
  },

  After: function(element, content) {
    return Element.insert(element, {after:content});
  }
};

var $continue = new Error('"throw $continue" is deprecated, use "return" instead');

....
```

Answer (score 1):

Some background

```
throw $continue
```

was used in an `Enumerable#each()` loop the same way `continue` is used in most logic control loops. It ignores the rest of the loop for that iteration and continues with the next item in the loop.

`Enumerable#each()` takes 2 parameters, a Javascript closure and the context, if you call `return` that ends the current closure with the current iteration and goes to the next item.

the `throw $continue` error handling was deprecated to use normal Javascript function control.

I would suggest looking at the error stack trace to see where the `throw $continue` is being called from and replace it with a `return`.

If you do remove the deprecated block then you will get normal Javascript errors instead of a helpful console message telling you to use `return` instead